# YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python (2.7.1+ or 3.4+) support. Press ENTER or type command to continue

Tags: linux, vim, python

I was editing my vimrc but after I had added tabnine (or I don't know is that's the problem), it shows this message every time I open a file with vim. The vim version is 8.1 and I'm on Linux. This is the output of `vim --version`:

```
    VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Jun 15 2019 16:41:15)
Included patches: 1-875, 878, 884, 948, 1046, 1365-1368, 1382, 1401
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
+arabic            +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+autocmd           +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autochdir         +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    +gettext           +netbeans_intg     +textprop
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +timers
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +title
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        -toolbar
-clientserver      +job               -perl              +user_commands
-clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visual
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
+conceal           +linebreak         -python3           +viminfo
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +vreplace
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildignore
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildmenu
+cursorshape       -lua               -ruby              +windows
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        +writebackup
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -X11
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xfontset
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xim
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xsmp
+eval              +mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        -xterm_save
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-4Pursk/vim-8.1.0875=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl
```

My vmrc:
[image]

Comment: Are you running *Debian*, right?

Comment: No, I'm on chrome OS haha

Comment: Copy and paste the .vimrc file on your post. The more details the better for helping you with your issue.

Comment: [Different ways to use (install) Vim Within Chrome OS (Chromebook)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m90ISq8RLJQ)

Comment: I don't think that the problem is the installation: I used 'sudo apt install vim'

Comment: Ok but we need to the .vimrc file's content added to your post for helping you better.

Comment: I did it, I edited the post

Answer (score 0):

For *every account* you wish using *tabnine* run on the terminal:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/codota/tabnine-vim
```

Then, run the following command:

```
 $ sudo apt install vim vim-youcompleteme git -y
```

Those steps has worked for me on a Debian distro. I just tried it out here on a VM.

References:

[tabnine - Instalation Instructions](https://www.tabnine.com/install/vim)

Comment: Unforunatly it doesn't wotk: ' E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root? ' I've already done that for tabnine

Comment: [Run the *apt command* as a *root* user and the *git clone command* as your user (*which you wish working with tabnine*). Did you try like that?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1208449/e-could-not-open-lock-file-var-lib-dpkg-lock-frontend-open-13-permission-d)

Comment: How do I run the command as a root user?

Comment: [You can run that on some terminal that way: *sudo command*. For instance, in your case, you wish running that way: *sudo apt install vim vim-youcompleteme git -y*.](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-sudo-command)

Comment: Thanks, in the command of the answer there was no 'sudo'. Now it works, thank you for the support